# I am trying to convert data into a JSON format and I am gettiing a JSON.parse() Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get a Syntax Error: "Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse () at IncomingMessage.". I don't know why I am getting that error.

Here is my code:

```
 const express = require("express");
 const https = require("http");
  const app = express();

 app.get("/", function(req, res){
const url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Accra&id=524901&appid=18a15324259a5d6f30f8e6610f8a4310";
https.get(url, function(response){
 
    response.on("data", function(data){
        const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(weatherData);
    //    console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your `response.on("data", ...` is probably returning a chunk of the response, not the full response

Comment: Try to log the `data` to see what it is.

Comment: You need to add to a string in the "data" event listener and use a second listener `response.on("end", ...)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incomplete Node HTTP.Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174227/incomplete-node-http-response)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to get the data before confirming wether it's completely received or not.
instead of reading at the on('data'), wait for on('end')
something like this :

```
    body = [];  
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {

        // Storing the chunk data
        body.push(chunk);
    });

    req.on('end', () => {

        // combining and parsing the chunk data to normal data
        const parsedBody = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        const message = parsedBody.split('=')[1];
        // Now you can parse the **message** to find the data
        console.log(JSON.parse(message))
    });
```

This will collect and parse the data once after collecting all the chunks.